# what is the meaning of "of some luck less Wight"? does "whisk" mean "shake or move rapidly"?

Tags: meaning

what is the meaning of "of some luck less Wight"? does "whisk" mean "shake or move rapidly"?

Now a phosphoric light shot from side to side over our heads; the laps
and hands and shoulders of several were simultaneously touched, struck,
or pawed by hands, the guitar meanwhile sailing round the room, now
near the ceiling, and then scuffling on the head and shoulders **of some
luck less Wight**. The bells **whisked** here and there, and a light thrumming
was maintained on the violin.

Comment: _Luckless_ is one word, and has always been as far as I know. I wonder if this is a transcription error.

Comment: Keep in mind that you should **always** include a source when you ask a question like this. Also I have noticed you have shown no research effort in your questions. Please try a dictionary and/or search engine first before posting.

Comment: The word wight, meaning person, is not a proper noun, and should not be started with a capital letter, unless it starts a sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Wight" means a person. I have only heard it used in a phrase such as you quote. It is not common in current UK English.

"Whisk" means to move to and fro, or in circles, within a confined space. The word really refers to the action of whisking or beating food items such as eggs or cream. So in the quoted text the bells are moving in a manner comparable to a whisk in a bowl.

On re-reading the whole quoted text a few more times I think the "whisked" refers to moving around the whole room. Compare to the movement of the phosphoric light  and the guitar. So for this "whisked" may refer more to the speed of movement and not suggesting movement within a small (bowl like) area. The light "shot", the guitar was "sailing" and the bells "whisked". The author is suggesting different patterns of movement for the different items.